# Database design 2 nullable columns or 1 multipurpose column?

Tags: database-design

I'm in charge of a rather large project as an intern and I'm starting to question some of my original decisions, but I am uncertain how to take appropriate measures to fix these issues.

**Business Logic:**

A `Load` can have a value for `Distance` which is some integer value **OR** it can have a `Position` indicated a panel point "P1", "P2", "P3".

**Question**:

Should I have two nullable fields or a single field that I just parse two see if it is an integer or not? If it is an integer I know it's a distance value, if not, it's a position value. Are there advantages to both?

I've read to avoid nullable fields, but at the same time a multipurpose field doesn't sound like the best decision either. I'm leaning towards multipurpose but I'm really uncertain what I should do for proper database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd have two nullable fields, it'll just save you from the extra code work you'll have to do later on. When extrapolating or calculate the database rows for some reason (a report or something) you wouldn't have to do checks on the column asking if its a varchar or int, that way you can just quickly get to manipulating the data.

The nullable fields may be against standard database design, but in the real world a 'perfect' database is hard to come by with the majority having at least a few questionable designs decisions. 
In the end though, do whatever will work for you and what you think will give you the least pain in maintenance.

Comment: Would it be better to make the Integer column required and check for Zeroes instead of nulls? I suppose the business logic doesn't require it to be null, it just won't have a value.

Thank you for your answer, though mostly opinion it has helped lead me to a decision I feel comfortable with making.

Comment: Mm, in retrospect of my personal experience, I think it'd be a good idea to put 0s instead of nulls as sometimes a DBNULL will throw an error in your procedures or queries and it took me a while to understand why. So yeah, a DEFAULT 0 would be good for your column, my opinion again..